# Why my bindService function fails?

Tags: android, service

I can't bind my service in my activity. Do you know why? BindService return false.
I have no idea why. No even exception is throw.

`public class GPSService extends Service {`

```
private final IBinder _IBinder = new GPSBinder( );


public class GPSBinder extends Binder {
    public GPSService getService( ) { 
        return GPSService.this;
    }
} 

@Override
public void onCreate( ) { 
    super.onCreate( );
    }

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {  
    return _IBinder;
}


@Override
public boolean onUnbind( Intent intent ){ 
    return super.onUnbind( intent ); 
}
```

Binding in onStart:

`servCon = new ServiceConnection( ){`

```
    @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            Log.d("GPS", "Serv conn");
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            Log.d("GPS", "Serv disc");
        }

    };
    boolean ret = bindService( new Intent( this, GPSService.class), servCon, Activity.BIND_AUTO_CREATE );
```

ret value is equals to false.

Comment: perhaps you didnt define it node in manifest.xml :)

Comment: I have this: <service android:name=".services.GPSService" /> 
Do i need user-permission too maybe?

Comment: can you please post the whole java source code of you Service and Activity and manifest file also . it seems a very easy error .

Comment: I would rather not to do this :/ But service looks just like this above.

Comment: okey check the packages name for the service and the package attribute in your manifest

Comment: Shouldn't os throw Security exception then?

Comment: package of my service class -> .services.GPSService.java
Manifest: <service android:name=".services.GPSService" />
<uses-permission android:name=".services.GPSService" />

Comment: Ok, problem solved. permission is not needed, in <service> i add android:enabled="true" and fixed package position. Now it works.